# Можно ли сохранить изменения в *.html файле?

Tags: javascript

Есть html файл с таблицами, напротив каждой таблицы нужно сделать select с выбором (согласовано, не согласовано). По факту прикрепил код. Мне интересно, можно ли совершить изменения в html файле и сохранить их в этом же файле (то есть все действия совершать на стороне клиента) по средством javascript.

```
<form name="r1" action="">
    <table border=1 width=730>
    <tr><td width=100>Четверг</td><td width=30>01</td><td width=80>08:49:57</td><td width=80>17:29:40</td><td width=220>опоздал на входе</td><td width=220></td></tr>
    <tr><td width=100>Пятница</td><td width=30>02</td><td width=80>08:49:14</td><td width=80>13:01:10</td><td width=220>опоздал на входе</td><td width=220>поспешил на выходе</td></tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor=red width=100>Суббота</td><td width=30>03</td><td width=80>&nbsp</td><td width=80>&nbsp</td><td width=220>&nbsp</td><td width=220>отсутствовал</td></tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor=red width=100>Воскресенье</td><td width=30>04</td><td width=80>&nbsp</td><td width=80>&nbsp</td><td width=220>&nbsp</td><td width=220>отсутствовал</td></tr>
        </table>
        <select name="t1">
        <option value="0">Согласовано</option>
        <option value="1" >Не согласовано</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

Comment: яваскрипт не имеет доступа к файлу html

Comment: а какими способами можно решить такую задачу ?

Comment: Только клиентскими - никакими

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо. Буду делать тогда на php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что речь идёт о **локальном** файле, открываемом **не** по HTTP.

И даже при этом напрямую нельзя.

Есть своеобразный способ обхода: если все скрипты страницы вшиты прямо внутрь неё, то текущее состояние страницы можно выдать пользователю в качестве **скачиваемого файла**.

Достаточно свежие браузеры, в комбинации с [`FileSaver.js`](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js), позволяют "скачивать" JS-строку как файл. Если без библиотек, то процесс состоит обычно из сборки `Blob` из строки и предложения его скачать через `window.saveAs`.

Это **никак не изменит исходный файл**, но загрузит пользователю файл с новым состоянием. Так что исходный файл можно распространять даже с сервера по HTTP, но чтобы загрузить обратно результат, уже потребуется серверная часть или сторонние каналы.